# Show pager dots on ion-slide-box

Tags: ion-slide-box

I want show pager dots by default in ion-slide-box :

i tried like this :

```
<ion-slide-box [options]="{pagination: true}">
  <ion-slide>
    <p> slide 1 </p> 
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
   <p> slide 2 </p> 
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

but it didn't work for please help.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide-box [options]="{pagination: true}">
    <ion-slide>
      <p> slide 1 </p>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      <p> slide 2 </p>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slide-box>
</ion-slides>
```